# SVN Merging Tree Conflict

Tags: svn

I've got into a situation like this:

I have a branch named A copied from trunk, and I also have another branch copied from trunk, named B. These branches were created in different time and the trunk was not the same when they were created.

The branch A stayed stuck for a while and I created branch B to fix some bugs. Now I have to first reintegrate branch B into A, then A into trunk.

The problem is that when I merge B into A, I got many tree conflicts. I tried ignoring ancestry and accepting B, but they didn't solve and I really have to perform the merge, in some cases both branches have modified the same file.

The only way I realized to perform this is manually merging. But I'm sure it has to have another way. My repo is on svn-1.6.

I really appreciate your help.

Regards,

Marlon Pascoal

Comment: Which kind of automated merge did you try (merge range of revisions, reintegrate a branch or merge two different trees)?

Answer (score 0):

I think manually merge is the best way.

When you created branch A and then branch B, the bug fixing on branch B should sync to branch A timely, if you need to reintegrate branch B into A.